# DataGrid - how to make both scrollbars always visible?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have pretty big DataGrid which doesn't fit into window:

```
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="17" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Name="dataGrid1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding DataList}" IsReadOnly="True" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStrategy, Mode=TwoWay}" AutoGeneratingColumn="DG_AutoGeneratingColumn">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding OpenStrategyViewCommand}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </DataGrid>
```

The problem is:

- vertical scrolling doesn't exist
- horizontal scrolling is at the bottom of the DataGrid, but not at the bottom of Window

Because there are no vertical scrolling it is not possible to scroll DataGrid to the bottom where horizontal scrolling is.

At both dimensions (vertical and horizontal) datagrid is larger than a window

I want to have two scrollbars in DataGrid but they should be always visible. How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

> Because there are no vertical scrolling it is not possible to scroll
>   DataGrid to the bottom where horizontal scrolling is.

It sounds like you haven't configured your sizing correctly, but I'm not that big on the WPF DataGrid so I can't tell you exactly what's wrong unfortunately.

For always displaying scrollbars, use the following two attributes:

```
<DataGrid
HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" >
```

Comment: ok now scrollbar is visible but it doesn't allow to scroll! i.e. it "grayed-out" even if lines doesn't fit on the screen

Comment: I suggest you try adding a scrollviewer, see the answer by ShadeOfGrey. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the visibility of both ScrollBars with Horizontal- and VerticalScrollBarVisibility on your DataGrid, but i think maybe you should put your grid inside a ScrollViewer as Anderson Holmström suggested.

[MSDN DataGrid Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Add [ScrollViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750665.aspx) around your DataGrid. Helps you control datagrid size, also as the other posters mentioned HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" control the visibility of the scrollbars.

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="17" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Name="dataGrid1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding DataList}" IsReadOnly="True" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStrategy, Mode=TwoWay}" AutoGeneratingColumn="DG_AutoGeneratingColumn">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding OpenStrategyViewCommand}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </DataGrid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: I can see horizontal scrollbar, but it doesn't work (always grayed out even when datagrid doesn't fit in the screen)

Comment: Can you add the grid column and row definitions to the question? I would like to take a look at them as well.